# Set spark.serializer to kryo with kryo.KryoException org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, session, apache-spark, exception, kryo

I get some entity from db with hibernate3 using Dao method(after the entity return, session is closed), and wrap it into a broadcast for all the executors. After setting spark.serializer to org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer, exception throw: KryoException org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException... no session or session was closed.
How should I get entity serialized without eager get all the value from db? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I register the hibernate entity with javaSerilizer, and bypass the problem;

Comment: Can you pls tell me how you did that? Thanks